# How to stop pyplot from overlapping histogram bins?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm sure there's an easy answer to this and I'm just looking at things wrong, but what's going on with my pyplot histogram? Here's the output; the data contains participants between the ages of 18 and 24, with no fractional ages (nobody's 18.5):

[image: pyplot histogram with overlapping bins]

Why are the bins staggered like this? The current width is set to 1, so each bar should be the width of a bin, right? The problem gets even worse when the width is less than 0.5, when the bars look like they're in completely different bins.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('F:\Python\Delete\Delete.csv')

age = csv.age
gender = csv.gender

new_age = age[~np.isnan(age)]
new_age_f = new_age[gender==2]
new_age_m = new_age[gender==1]

plt.hist(new_age_f, alpha=.80, label='Female', width=1, align='left')
plt.hist(new_age_m, alpha=.80, label='Male', width=1, align='left')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`plt.hist` does not have any argument `width`. If  `width` is specified, it is given to the underlying patch, meaning that the rectangle is made `1` wide. This has nothing to do with the bin width of the histogram and I would guess there are little to no reasons to ever use `width` in a histogram call at all.

Instead what you want is to specify the bins. You probably also want to use the same bins for both histogram plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(5)
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.DataFrame({"age" : np.random.randint(18,27, 20),
                    "gender" : np.random.randint(1,3,20)})

age = csv.age
gender = csv.gender

new_age = age[~np.isnan(age)]
new_age_f = new_age[gender==2]
new_age_m = new_age[gender==1]

bins = np.arange(new_age.values.min(),new_age.values.max()+2)

plt.hist(new_age_f, alpha=.40, label='Female', bins=bins, ec="k")
plt.hist(new_age_m, alpha=.40, label='Male', bins=bins,  ec="k")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Defining the bins fixed it right up. As a follow-up question, do you know why, if I omit both the bins and the width arguments, the histogram still comes out staggered? Why is the default behavior leaving [these giant bin-sized holes](http://imgur.com/aXXLBz2) in the output?

Comment: by default, matplotlib uses 10 bins between the minium and maximum value. Some bins like e.g. the one between 19.2 and 19.8 are then empty, because as you said you don't have anyone being 19.5 years old.